# How should I structure my routes and controllers in Laravel?

Tags: php, button, controller, routes, laravel-7

I've got two buttons on my page, which each have different behaviours when clicked. Currently I've got my routes and controllers set up like this...

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/users/button1clicked', 'UsersController@button1clicked');
Route::post('/users/button2clicked', 'UsersController@button2clicked');
```

**app/http/controllers/UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function button1clicked(Request $request){
      //Do something
}

    public function button2clicked(Request $request){
      //Do something else
}
```

}

It works ... but I don't think I'm following the correct convention for my controller, because controllers should just have the standard actions (index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy).

What would be a better way for me to structure this code?

Answer (score 0):

What does each button do? For example, if the button submits a form to 'save' an entity (say a 'Post' in a Blog app) then the form action can direct to the `PostController@store`. If the button click is intended to show a html form to create an Post, then the it can lead to `PostController@show`. The table below from the Laravel docs will help you.
[Route definitions conventions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyO7C.png)

Please also see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters.

If you are using ajax or axios to make async calls then you can call a function using button events (on-click for example) and that function can make a post (or any other async call to the relevant controller method ( `PostController@store`). Please let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: My apologies if  I didn't understand the question properly and the answer is too primitive and obvious. It seems you are well experienced and very knowledgeable about MVC pattern, I am just a novice.

Comment: No, I think you've understood the question right. :) I just seem to end up with buttons that do things that don't seem to fit the convention. For example one button starts a process that fetches values from an API and shows them on screen.